# Symfony asset function prepends / to http url

Tags: symfony, webpack, assets, webpack-dev-server

I've tried to add webpack to a Symfony 3.1 app. The problem is, when I add HMR, the asset function doesn't resolve correctly

```
// base.html.twig
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>

// app/config/config_dev.yml
framework:
    assets:
        base_path: "http://localhost:8080"
```

Result: `<script src="/http://localhost:8080/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js"></script>`

How can I tell Symfony to not prepend the starting `/` if the `base_path` begins with `http://`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base_urls. Protocol/host/port should not be used in base_path for assets.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets